# Google calendar API do not return events list

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

Recently after adding new events in Google calendar and try to fetch it from Google calendar API, I never get the new events list for the primary calendarId of my account.

Also I tried to fetch from developer console:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it
which gives the same empty list of items as response, even though the future events exists.

But I am able to fetch the events list of other calendar list. eg. Holidays, shared calendar from friends etc.

Comment: Are you authenticated? Do you get any error? Could you try performing an insert event operation on your primary calendar via the #try-it and see if that event gets listed?

Comment: Yes, creation of events from the API from my primary calendarId is not an issue. I see that events gets created in the calendar. But when I try to fetch these events from the API, I get nothing in the response.

Comment: More questions: Can you perform a get for the event you just insterted and see if it is there? Can you see those events in the web UI?

Comment: @SuhasGiriraj Was this issue resolved?

Comment: Same problem here. A secondary calendar with plenty of recurring events (visible in web GUI) but using python API,  events().list() does NOT return any events.  Setting singleEvents=True returns the instances, but that list is way too big so not a proper solution. Bug in google calendar API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also had the problem of `events().list(calendarId=<calendar_id>, singleEvents=False)` not returning any events (using python API). I tested with a secondary calendar with one recurring event. Solved by adding parameter `maxResults=9999`. It turned out that maxResults value 1413 or higher is needed to return the event. Weird, seems to be a bug.

Comment: Had the problem, that a one-off event was missing with singleEvents=True, fixed it with maxResults=9999.

Comment: Also, have this problem using .NET API and the official google NuGet package. Everything was alright but in one moment the events disappear. When I add 'maxResults = 2500' because this is the max value, the events appear. Thank you!

Comment: adding only `singleEvents=true` solved for me. If I use with `maxResults` doesn't work

Comment: so for the REST api I just had to add `?maxResults=9999` and I got what I wanted over 500 events... Thank you everybody....most specially for speaking opening to the public even when you think no one is listening cause thankfully we can read it later

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `singleEvents:true` to your request.

I was having the same issue. In my case, using Javascript, this works (returns several single, non-recurring events) :

```
  var calendar = googleapis.calendar('v3');
  calendar.events.list({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return callback(err);
    }
    console.log(response); 
    var events = response.items;
    if (events.length == 0) {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
      }
      return callback(null, events); 
    }
  });
```

But this does not (doesn't return any events including those that are on the 'primary' calendar and are single, non-recurring events). The only difference from above code is `singleEvents` parameter is commented out so it's value will default to `false`.

```
  var calendar = googleapis.calendar('v3');
  calendar.events.list({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    //singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return callback(err);
    }
    console.log(response); 
    var events = response.items;
    if (events.length == 0) {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
      }
      return callback(null, events); 
    }
  });
```

Comment: Setting `singleEvents` to `true` does not change the output in my case. It still lists no events.

Comment: I'm hoping someone can shed some light on why. They way that I interpret singleEvents: ("Whether to expand recurring events into instances and only return single one-off events and instances of recurring events, but not the  underlying recurring events themselves. Optional. The default is  False.") is that regardless of whether it is true or false, single (non-recurring) events will be returned but that doesn't seem to be the case. It does return single events in the same situation w/ singleEvents=false if query on private extended properties only (no timeMin,timeMax).

Comment: Setting singleEvents to True is not a solution since it returns all instances separately. singleEvents = False should also work. Is this a bug in google calendar API?

Comment: @Micrified and, were you able to solve this or work around it?

Comment: It did work for me 
I was fetching the list of events from a particular calendar and it was only giving me a list of few events and not all of them. 
added ```singleEvents:true``` in the query parameter and it gave me all the events